# java compilation version error "more recent version" except i do not have a more recent version installed! Minecraft server

Tags: java, minecraft

[image: all information needed]
JNI Error and compilation error
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: net/minecraft/bundler/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

just trying to get my minecraft server running. sorry for inexperience with java

i tried resetting my path to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351\bin and i made sure it was at the top but to no avail. What is going on?? I also already reinstalled and uninstalled 17 in an attempt to clean up whatever is going on. Didn't work

Comment: The error message tells you that the class expects a newer JDK than you're using. In other words: Java 8 is not new enough. Recent MC versions require at least Java 17 (or Java 16 for a short while). Class file version 61.0 implies Java 17.

Comment: "except i do not have a more recent version installed!" Then isn't "install a more recent version" the natural thing to do?

Comment: "didn't work" doesn't tell nearly enough. You probably didn't install it properly

Comment: Joachim Sauer, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you for explaining. I was reading it backwards, as if it was telling me it was using 61 but it needed 52.